# How can in run a dag with one task

Tags: python, airflow, scheduler

```
default_args = {
"owner": "airflow_admin",
"start_date": datetime(2017, 8, 29),
"schedule_interval":'*/5 * * * *'
 }
with DAG(
'my_first_dag',
catchup=False,
default_args=default_args,
) as dag:

   task1 = BashOperator(
   task_id='id1',
   bash_command=bash_.format('db1', 'tab1'))

task1
```

does anyone knows how to launch a dag with one task please, the code above don't work, the dag is launched properly

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your indentation is correct. Your task should be defined inside the scope of the `DAG` context manager, otherwise you must provide the `dag` parameter to your task:

Try:

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow_admin",
    "start_date": datetime(2017, 8, 29),
    "schedule_interval": "0 5 * * *"
}
with DAG('my_first_dag', catchup=False, default_args=default_args) as dag:
    task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='id1',
        bash_command=bash_.format('db1', 'tab1'))
```

Or without using context manager:

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow_admin",
    "start_date": datetime(2017, 8, 29),
    "schedule_interval": "0 5 * * *"
}
dag = DAG('my_first_dag', catchup=False, default_args=default_args)
task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='id1',
        bash_command=bash_.format('db1', 'tab1'),
        dag=dag)
```

Comment: Thank you. @Gabip but the dag was not launched. :/

Comment: thank you for your response. i changed my original post to run the dag evry five minutes. There is no error but the dag was not launched.

Comment: do you see what i mean?

Comment: what do you mean by wasn't launched? the dag was created properly but it wasn't scheduled?

Comment: What is the value of `DAG_SCHEDULE_INTERVAL`?

Comment: */5 * * * * @Gabip

Comment: Did you check from UI if the DAG is turned ON ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving schedule interval as parameter to dag, instead of in default_args?

```py
default_args = {
"owner": "airflow_admin",
"start_date": datetime(2017, 8, 29),
 }
with DAG(
'my_first_dag',
catchup=False,
default_args=default_args,
schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *",
) as dag:

   task1 = BashOperator(
   task_id='id1',
   bash_command=bash_.format('db1', 'tab1'))
```

Hope this works.